# Animation while closing Form in Android using Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7, delphi-10-seattle, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using **Delphi 10 seattle** for developing Android mobile application. And in that I have `form` and while closing that `form`, I need to have any **animation effect**. I have seen `TFloatAnimation` but I didn't find any help files for using it. Please help me to handle this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the code you've tried already.

Comment: Have you looked at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_FireMonkey_Animation_Effects

Comment: TFloatanimation works well once you have decided what it is that you want to animate.